# Реализация представления в Django ORM

Tags: python, orm, django

Здравствуйте.
Как можно реализовать вьюху (представление в mysql) в Django ORM.
Например, есть класс Группы, нам надо вытащить студентов (группы:'студенты', 'преподаватели')

```
class People:
    name = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=150)
    describe = models.CharField(u"Описание", max_length=150 )
```

Т.е. нам надо создать представление для того, чтобы потом связывать с этой моделью с полем id_stident

```
class Group_stud:
    id_student = ForeignKey(Student)
```

Вот модель Student'a нам нужна! 
Как сделать не знаю, в mysql можно было бы создать представление с фильтром и все было бы гуд, а у нас ORM, так не пойдет. Можно как нибудь такое реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно не то, что хотел, но этим можно обойтись.

Реализовал с помощью [class Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/) подсказал [@rnd_d](/users/672/rnd_d)

```
class StudentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(StudentManager, self).get_query_set().filter(groups__name='Students') # в User есть поле groups и идет фильтр по полю name

class User(User):
    students = StudentManager()
```

Выходные данные

```
>>> from main.models import User
>>> User.students.all()
[<User: Petr>]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: Очень познавательно, но т.к. англ храмает, не всю суть улавливаю. Можно в примерах как вы используете такие связи и др.